# How to calculate the pseudoinverse of a symmetric matrix given its eigenvalue decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a singular symmetric matrix $A$ and the system $Ax = b$, knowing that there exists a solution, how could one find a pseudoinverse given the eigenvalue decomposition s.t. $x = A^*b$ ?

Comment: Do you acknowledge that the inverse is also symmetric?

Comment: No, I didn't. Could you guide me how to construct the matrix A* from the eigenvalue decomposition such that x is a solution to the above system? (only how one would construct that theoretically)

Comment: I think it was rude of you to delete this question. I was going to answer you regarding your request for an application of my answer but since you deleted the question, its becoming clear that you just want to hide this answer intentionally...perhaps to get away with cheating?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A$ to be a symmetric matrix. By SVD, $A=P^{T}DP$ where $P$ is orthonormal and $D=\text{Diag}(\lambda_{i})$. Define $A^{-1}=P^{T}D^{-1}P$, where $D^{-1}=\text{Diag}(\lambda_{i}^{*})$ where :
$$
\lambda_{i}^{*}=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}& \text{if $\lambda_{i}\neq0$} \\
0 &\text{if $\lambda_{i}=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
You should know that $A=AA^{-1}A$. Thus, we shall show that $A^{-1}=A^{-1}AA^{-1}$ where $A^{-1}$ is also symmetric. Let $A^{-1}=P^{T}D^{-1}P$, we have that :
$$
(A^{-1})^{T}=(P^{T}D^{-1}P)^{T}=P^{T}D^{-1}P^{T}=A^{-1}
$$
Thus, $A^{-1}$ is symmetric. Now we have that :
$$
A^{-1}AA^{-1}=P^{T}D^{-1}PP^{T}DPP^{T}D^{-1}P=P^{T}D^{-1}P=A^{-1}
$$

Comment: If you wish that I expand my answer to include a generalization of any type of $m\times n$ rectangular matrix, I would be happy to answer :)

Comment: I don't think it's correct. I used this procedure in Matlab but it didn't yield a correct solution. I think this is because D is not invertible... (I "inverted" it in the way you proposed)

Comment: I stick to my answer :) . Note that $DD^{-1}=I_{r}$ where $I_{r}$ is the partial identity matrix corresponding to the rank $r$ of $A$. @HeinrichBrack

Comment: ok I exactly had the same solution, the previous problem had been for regular matrices, but I didn't think that one is allowed to do that.

Comment: would you mind trying out the method, because I'm still doubting it a bit. Take for example the matrix [1, 2, 3; 2, 4, 6; 3, 6, 5]

Comment: Of course, where are you looking to apply them? MATLAB? I can give you an example and the procedure.

Comment: The example that you gave me is a square matrix, I thought you wanted a rectangular matrix

Comment: yeah but I'm given a singular square matrix, a non square matrix has no eigenvalues...